# tibble::add_row to nested tibble throws error under tidyr 1.0.0

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

In a former version of `tidyr` I was able to add rows to a nested tibble using `tibble::add_row`. After updating to version 1.0.0 I get the following error:

> Error: `levels.vctrs_list_of()` not supported.

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr) # version 1.0.0

mtcars %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -cyl) %>% colnames) %>% 
  tibble::add_row(cyl = "all cyl", data = NA)
#> Error: `levels.vctrs_list_of()` not supported.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

And here is the same call using tidyr 0.8.3

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr) # version 0.8.3

 mtcars %>% 
   tidyr::nest(-cyl) %>% 
   tibble::add_row(cyl = "all cyl", data = NA)
  #> # A tibble: 4 x 2
  #>   cyl     data              
  #>   <chr>   <list>            
  #> 1 6       <tibble [7 × 10]> 
  #> 2 4       <tibble [11 × 10]>
  #> 3 8       <tibble [14 × 10]>
  #> 4 all cyl <lgl [1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Are other users experiencing the same or is this specific to my system environment?
Do I need to update other packages to get this running?
Is there a workaround?
Should I open an issue on Github?

**Update:** In the comments someone suggested updating the `vctrs` package. But after updating to the latest version 0.2.1 the same error still appears.

**background / context**

I should elaborate why I wanted to use `add_row` with `data = NA` in the first place.

My original script looked somewhat like this:

```
# tidyr version 0.8.3 add_row was working
iris %>% 
  tidyr::nest(-Species) %>% 
  tibble::add_row(Species = "All species", data = NA) %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::modify_at(4, ~ as_tibble(select(iris, -Species)))
```

Which returned a nested tibble with all categories as well as an overall category.

Under tidyr 1.0.0 my code looks like this and throws said error:

```
# tidyr version 1.0.0 where add_row does not work
iris %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -Species) %>% colnames) %>% 
  tibble::add_row(Species = "All species", data = NA) %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::modify_at(data, nrow(.), ~ as_tibble(select(iris, -Species))))
```

Since `add_row` is not working under tidyr 1.0.0 anymore, the next best similar alternative is as @IceCreamToucan suggested `bind_rows`.

```
# tidyr version 1.0.0 alternative with dpylr::bind_rows
iris %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -Species) %>% colnames) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(tibble(Species = "All species", data = NA)) %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::modify_at(data, nrow(.), ~ as_tibble(select(iris, -Species))))
```

However, since the syntax of `tidyr::nest` got more verbose under version 1.0.0 I tried to streamline the code and this seems by far the most straightforward approach, which I should have chosen from beginning on:

```
# What I should have been doing in the first place
iris %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(mutate(iris, Species = "All species")) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -Species) %>% colnames)
```

Comment: can you add output from old version? and  `packageVersion("tidyr")`

Comment: added output of older tidy version

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to use `bind_rows`. It looks like `bind_rows` produces a warning when you are adding to a list column, while `add_row` produces an error.

```
mtcars %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -cyl) %>% colnames) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(cyl), as.character) %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(cyl = 'all cyl', data = NA))

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   cyl     data              
#   <chr>   <list>            
# 1 6       <tibble [7 x 10]> 
# 2 4       <tibble [11 x 10]>
# 3 8       <tibble [14 x 10]>
# 4 all cyl <NULL>
# Warning message:
# In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#   Vectorizing 'vctrs_list_of' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

Comment: Nice idea, this is only slightly more verbose than `add_row` and does what it should.

Answer (score 2):

Following akrun's advice I installed the devel version of `dplyr` (and also `tibble`, `tidyr`, `vctrs`, `tidyselect`) and it seems that the next official `tidyverse` versions will solve this issue.

First of all, the original error message is now specific, and makes clear that adding a row without a common type is not possible.

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -Species) %>% colnames) %>% 
  tibble::add_row(tibble(Species = "All species", data = NA))
#> Error: No common type for `..1$data` <list> and `..2$data` <logical>.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This behavior can be circumvented by wrapping `NA` in `list()`. Then we could use `modify_at` to replace the `list(NA)` with the original tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
   tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -Species) %>% colnames) %>% 
   tibble::add_row(Species = "All species", data = list(NA)) %>% 
   mutate(data = modify_at(data, nrow(.), ~ as_tibble(select(iris, -Species))))
#>  A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Species     data              
#>   <chr>       <list>            
#> 1 setosa      <tibble [50 × 4]> 
#> 2 versicolor  <tibble [50 × 4]> 
#> 3 virginica   <tibble [50 × 4]> 
#> 4 All species <tibble [150 × 4]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, now it is also possible to add `tibbles` as data argument with `add_row` by wrapping them in a list as in `list(as_tibble(select(iris, -Species)))`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -Species) %>% colnames) %>% 
  tibble::add_row(Species = "All species",
                  data = list(as_tibble(select(iris, -Species))))
    #>  A tibble: 4 x 2
    #>   Species     data              
    #>   <chr>       <list>            
    #> 1 setosa      <tibble [50 × 4]> 
    #> 2 versicolor  <tibble [50 × 4]> 
    #> 3 virginica   <tibble [50 × 4]> 
    #> 4 All species <tibble [150 × 4]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Nevertheless, this approach is still more verbose then the one I came up with as an intermediate solution, which I will use from now on:

```
iris %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(mutate(iris, Species = "All species")) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -Species) %>% colnames)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a type issue and if we are appending `NA` elements in the `list` column, try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
  tidyr::nest(data = dplyr::select(., -cyl) %>% colnames) %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.character(cyl)) %>%
  dplyr::add_row(cyl = "all cyl", 
    data = list(as.tibble(setNames(as.list(rep(NA_real_, ncol(mtcars) - 1)), 
         setdiff(names(mtcars), 'cyl')))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When running your code it throws the same error as before: `Error: levels.vctrs_list_of() not supported.`

Comment: @TimTeaFan  May be it is the version difference.  I used the `devel` version and it is working for me

Comment: That's interesting. I should try the `devel` version and see if my original issue is fixed.

Comment: Now using the `devel` version of `tidyr` and still the same error. Starting to wonder whether this is 'only' a `tidyr` issue or whether other package such as `tibble` and `dplyr` might contribute to it. I also realized that the original function `add_row` is from `tibble` and only imported to `dplyr`.

Comment: I meant I used the `devel` version of `dplyr`

Comment: I now updated all involved packages to `devel` version and this solves the issue completely. Thanks for the advice.